# Lazy loading in hibernate, for this scenario

Tags: hibernate

I have a table called MKDoc(name varchar, author varchar, attachment blob).

I want to display name and author to the user, as link. when the user clicks on the link, the attachment will gets loaded and saved to user system. I want the attachment to be lazy loaded. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on the attachment property in your Hibernate mapping, put in the attribute lazy="true" and that should do it.